# Select Distinct but with column's value

Tags: mysql

Here is what I want.

Let's say we have this table

```
Name  Email          Department             Branch
------------------------------------------------------
John  john@test.ca   Information Technology SAP
John  john@test.ca   Not Available          Not Available
Bret  brett@test.ca  Emergency Response     911
Bret  brett@test.ca  Not Available          Not Available
diana diana@test.ca  Not Available          Not Available
```

Now what I basically want is to get the following results:

If John has "Information Technology" and "Not Available" it will make "Information Technology" a priority. Basically it will only show Not Available row if John doesn't belong to any other department. 
so the result table will be like this:

```
Name  Email         Department             Branch
-----------------------------------------------------
John  john@test.ca  Information Technology SAP
Bret  brett@test.ca Emergency Response     911
Diana diana@test.ca Not Available          Not Available
```

Thanks!

Comment: Someone may prove me wrong, but I do not believe you can do this in SQL. You will need to retrieve the data then use some programming to massage the results.

Comment: You can do this in SQL, but consider storing "Not available" as NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data you need a `CASE` expression to check for `'Not Available'` and consider it as `NULL` so you can aggregate (with `MIN` or `MAX`):

```
select name, email,
  coalesce(
    max(case when department = 'Not Available' then null else department end),
    'Not Available'
  ) department,
  coalesce(
    max(case when branch = 'Not Available' then null else branch end),
    'Not Available'
  ) branch
from tablename
group by name, email
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Sc8zREDpQZmwnBXo6S7wD/1).
Results:

```
| name  | email         | department             | branch        |
| ----- | ------------- | ---------------------- | ------------- |
| Bret  | brett@test.ca | Emergency Response     | 911           |
| diana | diana@test.ca | Not Available          | Not Available |
| John  | john@test.ca  | Information Technology | SAP           |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL  
,email VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
,department VARCHAR(50)  NULL
,branch VARCHAR(50) NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'John','john@test.ca','Information Technology','SAP'),
(2,'John','john@test.ca',NULL,NULL),
(3,'Bret','brett@test.ca','Emergency Response','911'),
(4,'Bret','brett@test.ca',NULL,NULL),
(5,'diana','diana@test.ca',NULL,NULL);

SELECT name
     , email
     , MAX(department) department
     , MAX(branch) branch 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP  
    BY name
     , email;
+-------+---------------+------------------------+--------+
| name  | email         | department             | branch |
+-------+---------------+------------------------+--------+
| Bret  | brett@test.ca | Emergency Response     | 911    |
| diana | diana@test.ca | NULL                   | NULL   |
| John  | john@test.ca  | Information Technology | SAP    |
+-------+---------------+------------------------+--------+
```